# Node.js : Execute a rest call inside if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

I am using Node JS with express and I want to create a new user in my db with a REST call if the user logs in successfully with facebook. This code is just a slight modification of the heroku node.js facebook app : https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs/blob/master/web.js

Here's what i've tried

```
             //create Parse Object
    var parse_app_id = process.env.PARSE_APP_ID;
    var parse_master_key = process.env.PARSE_MASTER_KEY;
    var nodeParse = new Parse(parse_app_id, parse_master_key);

function handle_facebook_request(req, res) {

  // if the user is logged in
  if (req.facebook.token) {

    async.parallel([

       function(cb) {
        // query 4 friends and send them to the socket for this socket id
        req.facebook.get('/me/friends', { limit: 4 }, function(friends) {
          req.friends = friends;
          cb();
        });
      },
      function(cb) {
        // query 16 photos and send them to the socket for this socket id
        req.facebook.get('/me/photos', { limit: 16 }, function(photos) {
          req.photos = photos;
          cb();
        });
      }

    ], function() {
      render_page(req, res);
      nodeParse.signUp('',{ username: 'tajmahal', password: 'stuff'}, function(err, response) {
            console.log(response);
      });
    });

  } 
}

app.get('/', handle_facebook_request);
app.post('/', handle_facebook_request);
```

`handle_facebook_request` is executed when the app is requested...everything works fine besides the user creation.

`signUp` creates a user when its outside of the conditional (so the function works)

How can I fix this?

Comment: try replacing the call to signUp with something simpler: `setTimeout(function() { console.log('called') }, 100);'` and see if the callback gets called. I'm not familiar with nodeParse but with a simple callback the code seems to work.